Does 剣聖 only apply to famous swordsmen, or can it apply to a master of any type of weapon?
The word 剣聖 kensei is translated as "Sword Saint" in English and applies to men like Miyamoto Musashi who were famously great samurai and skilled swordsmen.  Does the term 剣聖 apply generally to any suitably great/famous samurai, even if they were famous for a weapon other than a sword?  Or if I had a samurai who was as famously skilled with, say, a yari or a naginata or a yumi as Miyamoto was with a sword, would they be called something else?  For that matter could it theoretically apply to a fighter pilot or modern weapon user? I know 剣 is "sword" but am unsure if it has that specific physical connotation here or is using 剣 more metaphorically.  My Japanese may generously be described as "meager" and I've been unable to find a good answer on my own.

I'm not an expert so I'm unsure what exact weapon falls under 剣, but that said, it would sound very weird if the term was applied to something like guns, fighter jets etc. IMO it exclusively refers to swords, as in something physically akin to knives.
